# Can't send Message - SMTP

Tags: java, smtp, mail-server

I am in the process of creating a SMTP-client where I can send a message through mail. I then have a problem - I have used different mailserver-ids and ports, but I can't get it sent, to work.

I've for example tried to use hotmail.com (live.com) and gmail.com.

Google/Gmail:
- Mail server: smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 587

And got no luck. Someone who can guide me and tell me what it is I'm doing wrong and how to enter and use the necessary informations?

***Here are the codes:***

SMTPConnection.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**Open an SMTP connection to a remote machine and send one mail.*/
public class SMTPConnection {
/* The socket to the server */
public Socket connection;

/* Streams for reading and writing the socket */
public BufferedReader fromServer;
public DataOutputStream toServer;

/* Just to make it look nicer */
private static final int SMTP_PORT = 25;
private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";

/* Are we connected? Used in close() to determine what to do. */
private boolean isConnected = false;

/*
 * Create an SMTPConnection object. Create the socket and the associated
 * streams. Send HELO-command and check for errors.
 */
public SMTPConnection(Envelope envelope) throws IOException {
    connection = new Socket(envelope.DestAddr, SMTP_PORT);
    fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    toServer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

    String reply = fromServer.readLine();
    if (parseReply(reply) != 220) {
        System.out.println("Error in connect.");
        System.out.println(reply);
        return;
    }
    String localhost = (InetAddress.getLocalHost()).getHostName();
    try {
        sendCommand("HELO " + localhost, 250);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("HELO failed. Aborting.");
        return;
    }
    isConnected = true;
}

/*
 * Send the message. Simply writes the correct SMTP-commands in the correct
 * order. No checking for errors, just throw them to the caller.
 */
public void send(Envelope envelope) throws IOException {
    sendCommand("MAIL FROM:<" + envelope.Sender + ">", 250);
    sendCommand("RCPT TO:<" + envelope.Recipient + ">", 250);
    sendCommand("DATA", 354);
    sendCommand(envelope.Message.toString() + CRLF + ".", 250);
}

/*
 * Close the connection. Try to send QUIT-commmand and then close the
 * socket.
 */
public void close() {
    isConnected = false;
    try {
        sendCommand("QUIT", 221);
        connection.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to close connection: " + e);
        isConnected = true;
    }
}

/*
 * Send an SMTP command to the server. Check for reply code. Does not check
 * for multiple reply codes (required for RCPT TO).
 */
private void sendCommand(String command, int rc) throws IOException {
    String reply = null;

    toServer.writeBytes(command + CRLF);
    reply = fromServer.readLine();
    if (parseReply(reply) != rc) {
        System.out.println("Error in command: " + command);
        System.out.println(reply);
        throw new IOException();
    }

}

/* Parse the reply line from the server. Returns the reply code. */
private int parseReply(String reply) {
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(reply);
    String replycode = parser.nextToken();
    return (new Integer(replycode)).intValue();
}

/* Destructor. Closes the connection if something bad happens. */
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if (isConnected) {
        close();
    }
    super.finalize();
}
}
```

MailClient.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**A simple mail client with a GUI for sending mail.*/
public class MailClient extends Frame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
/* The stuff for the GUI. */
private Button btSend = new Button("Send");
private Button btClear = new Button("Clear");
private Button btQuit = new Button("Quit");
private Label serverLabel = new Label("Local mailserver:");
private TextField serverField = new TextField("", 40);
private Label fromLabel = new Label("From:");
private TextField fromField = new TextField("", 40);
private Label toLabel = new Label("To:");
private TextField toField = new TextField("", 40);
private Label subjectLabel = new Label("Subject:");
private TextField subjectField = new TextField("", 40);
private Label messageLabel = new Label("Message:");
private TextArea messageText = new TextArea(10, 40);

/**
 * Create a new MailClient window with fields for entering all the relevant
 * information (From, To, Subject, and message).
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public MailClient() {
    super("Java Mailclient");

    /*
     * Create panels for holding the fields. To make it look nice, create an
     * extra panel for holding all the child panels.
     */
    Panel serverPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    Panel fromPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    Panel toPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    Panel subjectPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    Panel messagePanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    serverPanel.add(serverLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    serverPanel.add(serverField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fromPanel.add(fromLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    fromPanel.add(fromField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    toPanel.add(toLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    toPanel.add(toField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    subjectPanel.add(subjectLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    subjectPanel.add(subjectField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    messagePanel.add(messageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    messagePanel.add(messageText, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Panel fieldPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    fieldPanel.add(serverPanel);
    fieldPanel.add(fromPanel);
    fieldPanel.add(toPanel);
    fieldPanel.add(subjectPanel);

    /*
     * Create a panel for the buttons and add listeners to the buttons.
     */
    Panel buttonPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
    btSend.addActionListener(new SendListener());
    btClear.addActionListener(new ClearListener());
    btQuit.addActionListener(new QuitListener());
    buttonPanel.add(btSend);
    buttonPanel.add(btClear);
    buttonPanel.add(btQuit);

    /* Add, pack, and show. */
    add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
    show();
}

static public void main(String argv[]) {
    new MailClient();
}

/* Handler for the Send-button. */
class SendListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Sending mail");

        /* Check that we have the local mailserver */
        if ((serverField.getText()).equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Need name of local mailserver!");
            return;
        }

        /* Check that we have the sender and recipient. */
        if ((fromField.getText()).equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Need sender!");
            return;
        }
        if ((toField.getText()).equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Need recipient!");
            return;
        }

        /* Create the message */
        Message mailMessage = new Message(fromField.getText(),
                toField.getText(), subjectField.getText(),
                messageText.getText());

        /*
         * Check that the message is valid, i.e., sender and recipient
         * addresses look ok.
         */
        if (!mailMessage.isValid()) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Create the envelope, open the connection and try to send the
         * message.
         */
        try {
            Envelope envelope = new Envelope(mailMessage,
                    serverField.getText());

            SMTPConnection connection = new SMTPConnection(envelope);
            connection.send(envelope);
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException error) {
            System.out.println("Sending failed: " + error);
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Mail sent succesfully!");
    }
}

/* Clear the fields on the GUI. */
class ClearListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clearing fields");
        fromField.setText("");
        toField.setText("");
        subjectField.setText("");
        messageText.setText("");
    }
}

/* Quit. */
class QuitListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

Message.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
/*Mail message.*/
public class Message {
/* The headers and the body of the message. */
public String Headers;
public String Body;

/*
 * Sender and recipient. With these, we don't need to extract them from the
 * headers.
 */
private String From;
private String To;

/* To make it look nicer */
private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";

/*
 * Create the message object by inserting the required headers from RFC 822
 * (From, To, Date).
 */
public Message(String from, String to, String subject, String text) {
    /* Remove whitespace */
    From = from.trim();
    To = to.trim();
    Headers = "From: " + From + CRLF;
    Headers += "To: " + To + CRLF;
    Headers += "Subject: " + subject.trim() + CRLF;

    /*
     * A close approximation of the required format. Unfortunately only GMT.
     */
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
    String dateString = format.format(new Date());
    Headers += "Date: " + dateString + CRLF;
    Body = text;
}

/* Two functions to access the sender and recipient. */
public String getFrom() {
    return From;
}

public String getTo() {
    return To;
}

/*
 * Check whether the message is valid. In other words, check that both
 * sender and recipient contain only one @-sign.
 */
public boolean isValid() {
    int fromat = From.indexOf('@');
    int toat = To.indexOf('@');

    if (fromat < 1 || (From.length() - fromat) <= 1) {
        System.out.println("Sender address is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    if (toat < 1 || (To.length() - toat) <= 1) {
        System.out.println("Recipient address is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    if (fromat != From.lastIndexOf('@')) {
        System.out.println("Sender address is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    if (toat != To.lastIndexOf('@')) {
        System.out.println("Recipient address is invalid");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/* For printing the message. */
public String toString() {
    String res;

    res = Headers + CRLF;
    res += Body;
    return res;
}
}
```

Envelope.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
/*SMTP envelope for one mail message.*/
public class Envelope {
/* SMTP-sender of the message (in this case, contents of From-header. */
public String Sender;

/* SMTP-recipient, or contents of To-header. */
public String Recipient;

/* Target MX-host */
public String DestHost;
public InetAddress DestAddr;

/* The actual message */
public Message Message;

/* Create the envelope. */
public Envelope(Message message, String localServer)
        throws UnknownHostException {
    /* Get sender and recipient. */
    Sender = message.getFrom();
    Recipient = message.getTo();

    /*
     * Get message. We must escape the message to make sure that there are
     * no single periods on a line. This would mess up sending the mail.
     */
    Message = escapeMessage(message);

    /*
     * Take the name of the local mailserver and map it into an InetAddress
     */
    DestHost = localServer;
    try {
        DestAddr = InetAddress.getByName(DestHost);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("Unknown host: " + DestHost);
        System.out.println(e);
        throw e;
    }
    return;
}

/*
 * Escape the message by doubling all periods at the beginning of a line.
 */
private Message escapeMessage(Message message) {
    String escapedBody = "";
    String token;
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(message.Body, "\n", true);

    while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) {
        token = parser.nextToken();
        if (token.startsWith(".")) {
            token = "." + token;
        }
        escapedBody += token;
    }
    message.Body = escapedBody;
    return message;
}

/* For printing the envelope. Only for debug. */
public String toString() {
    String res = "Sender: " + Sender + '\n';
    res += "Recipient: " + Recipient + '\n';
    res += "MX-host: " + DestHost + ", address: " + DestAddr + '\n';
    res += "Message:" + '\n';
    res += Message.toString();

    return res;
}
}
```

And.. after running the program above, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in command: MAIL FROM:<azmibobo2650@gmail.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i17sm4367728wru.39 - gsmtp
Sending failed java.io.IOException
```

Someone who can help?

Comment: Too much code. Can you please [edit] your question reduce it to a [mcve]? Also include the error you get. See [ask].

Comment: Also, why reinvent the wheel instead of using JavaMail?

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the advise, it's done :D

Comment: @Robert, it's not something we have learned so far in teaching, the teacher has given us a half-finished code that we have to complete.

Comment: Ok, for teaching that's different, I guess. But now it gets complicated, as GMail wants TLS encryption. You'd have to find a crypto library (like bouncy castle), and implement all the TLS stuff. This is hard. I'd double check with the teacher if this is still in the scope of this project. Maybe you can switch to another provider that doesn't insist on TLS?

Comment: @Robert, Gmail is not a requirement every provider will work as long as I can send the message to the email address.

Comment: @Robert, what about a live.com, I have an xxx@hotmail.com mail. Which provider will be easiest? And how to apply it.

Comment: Try them! :-) BTW, when I run `host gmail.com` it says to use gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com as mail server, and when I `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` I can enter the SMTP commands and send myself an email without TLS. Maybe try sending from a non-gmail address, like your hotmail address? (Just guessing, though).

Comment: @Robert, just did. I tried to use the JavaMail, when using that I get the following; Username and Password not accepted. Tried different accounts, still same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212211/discussion-between-carsi-and-robert).